# http://localhost:[portnumber] - in tomcat seems to an error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, internal-server-error

My tomcat version 7.0 doesnot get open.If type `"http://localhost:9191"` in browser, *page not found error* is obtained.

and if try running any application in eclipse juno my tomcat throws **http:404 request resource not found error**

anyone give suggestion what is problem with my tomcat7.0

```
HTTP Status 404 - /formregister/user

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /formregister/user

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Tomcat log in my console :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\lms_server\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1732)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:42)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;c:\ruby\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C:\lms_server\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\bin;C:\opt\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Mvcvalid' did not find a matching property.
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8585"]
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9090"]
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1662 ms
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:55 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [446] milliseconds.
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\docs
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\examples
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@3fde891b')
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\host-manager
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\manager
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8585"]
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9090"]
Jul 4, 2014 11:13:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1948 ms
```

Now i have reinstalled my tomcat and after that also it shows me same above log(error) in my tomcat console ? Actually i had set

```
set CATALINA_HOME = C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54(my unzipped tomcat folder)

set CLASSPATH= C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\lib

set Path=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin
```

Comment: Can you verify your port# Goto tomcat>conf folder
Edit server.xml
Search "Connector port" and check port#

Comment: actually i changed  my port number to 9191.Because the tomcat says port 8080 is already exist

Comment: What error you see when you start your tomcat? Can you error detail?

Comment: http status:404   Message:/mvcvaild/loginPage   Description:"Request resource is not available"

Comment: We will first concentrate on basic problem to access http://localhost:9191 and then application access issue from tomcat. How do you start your tomcat? 1. Windows Service 2. from Console or 3. from Eclipse. If you start it console OR Eclipse then send me startup log from console before you trigger request to access your application

Comment: You're using the wrong binary for it - you're on a 64-bit machine and you're using the 32-bit version.

Comment: I have reinstalled tomcat(64bit) now and i have changed my CATALINA_HOME but it still shows me running in the same old path "c:/lms_server/apache-server-7.0.34" and shows same above log.How can i change that ?